# How to disable keyword / text suggestion in Spyder 4?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Specifically this popup box:

[image]

It appears almost every time I type anything, and it's kind of getting in the way.

I have disabled code completion in the settings, and uninstalled Kite, and disabled Jedi. Any ideas?

Comment: This is truly a puzzling feature of Spyder. Typically it recommends a single word for me, when I don't want any help at all, and takes me 2-3 seconds to do what used to take me 0.5 seconds. Glad you asked I had tried turning off the non-advanced options and no luck!

Comment: This will be improved in Spyder 4.1.0, to be released in a couple of weeks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) To disable those completions (called fallback completions) in Spyder 5, you need to go to

`Tools > Preferences > Completion and Linting > General`

and deactivate the option called `Enable Fallback provider`.

For Spyder 4, please go to

`Tools > Preferences > Completion and Linting > Advanced`

and deactivate the option called `Enable fallback completions`.

Comment: Note this question inspired the more basic question: what are fallback completions, exactly? What are the, how are they different from other types of completions? For instance when I turn off fallback completions I'm still getting these popups. I'm not sure if this is another type of completion or the disable didn't take. I just don't understand what these are. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60332187/what-are-fallback-completions-in-spyder

Comment: @Sandbo, code completion is triggered automatically after a dot in Python. If you don't want to see that, you'd need to disable all completions by going to `Tools > Preferences > Completion and linting > Completion` and deactivating the option called `Enable code completion`.

Comment: I deactivated the option, but it still shows up even after restarting.

Comment: Too many suggestions in spyder, so many that the editor is slow. I am trying all the permutations of the settings, but nothing changes.

Comment: I unchecked all of the boxes in every tab under `Completion and linting`. I found this was the only way to get rid of all of the pop-up boxes and other stuff

Comment: I'm trying to type N=100 and someone keeps popping up to tell me that I want N=1000..... Very frustrating. What works is to type a space bar after the 100. But why should I have to!! I've tried disabling a few things, none working so far. I admit I had blamed Kite, but seems to be Spyder.

Comment: @Tunneller, precisely by deactivating the option I mention above you'll get rid of those completions (I updated the answer for Spyder 5).

Comment: Thanks, so basically this disables everything @Carlos? On a related note, whatever I have at the moment will at least sometimes convert the text input into "overtype" mode as opposed to more usual "insert" mode. Overtype always has to be wrong :-) Looking forward to Spyder 5 - there are a lot of things about Spyder 4 that I enjoy.

Comment: That option disables all text completions, yes. And Spyder 5 was released last April. We're at version 5.0.5 right now.

Comment: I'm getting this behavior in Spyder 5.2.1.  Also in the help panel there is a lock icon that stays the same even if I click it.  This is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution that worked here. however, what did work was by going to Tools > Preferences > Completion and linting > Completion and deactivating the option called Enable code completion and the option enable code snippets.