# How to configure spyder 4 to behave like spyder 3

Tags: spyder

I just installed spyder 4.0.1 and am overwhelmed by all the bells and whistles.  Which settings should I change/uncheck in order to get back to spyder 3 default behaviour?

Two most pressing problems are with the auto-complete (using TAB) in the editor:

1. The first item is black on dark blue and therefore illegible.  Can I adjust that?
2. There are way too many irrelevant suggestions.  Can I adjust that?

(Python/anaconda/win7 in case it makes a difference.)

[image]

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) This is so vague that I voted to be closed, sorry. If you really want an answer, please provide a more detailed question.

Comment: _(Question asker here)_ Well, perhaps I should have said, Spyder 3 *default* behaviour to make it more precise, but I will add something narrower too.

Comment: Please post a screenshot of what you're seeing in your point `1.`.

Comment: Screenshot added to illustrate points 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) My answers:

> The first item is black on dark blue and therefore illegible. Can I adjust that?

No, but that dark blue color comes from the Windows classic theme, which is really ugly. In the normal Windows 10 theme things look as expected:

[image: completion widget with the normal Windows 10 theme]

> There are way too many irrelevant suggestions. Can I adjust that?

Yes. Please see my answer about that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59724907/438386

Comment: 1. Beauty is irrelevant. Other programs I use display things just fine, and so did spyder 3.

Comment: 2. There are a few other options besides Fallback.  How should I set them to be more like spyder 3?  (I don't remember what options spyder 3 offered as I hadn't played with them.)

Comment: 1. I'm really not sure what changed between Spyder 3 and 4 that made that color different, but you're welcome to delve into our source code and try to find it.

Comment: 2. Sorry but that comment is as vague as your original question.

Comment: 2. Where can I find documentation on the Autocomplete options in Spyder?