# What are fallback completions in Spyder?

Tags: python, spyder

There is an option in the Spyder IDE (Tools->Preferences->Completion and linting->Advanced) to activate *fallback completions*:

[image]

What are fallback completions, how are they supposed to work and help? I have googled it and not found a description.

Note this question was inspired by this question complaining (implicitly) about fallback completions: [How to disable keyword / text suggestion in Spyder 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59707973/how-to-disable-keyword-text-suggestion-in-spyder-4)

There, it isn't really explained what this feature is supposed to be, how it is supposed to work, but basically how to turn it off using the above interface. I am not trying to turn them off I am trying to find out what exactly are fallback completions, and how are they different from other types of completion going on?

Comment: That question is not exactly a duplicate of this but it describes what fallback completions are.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba I disagree with this being closed and being a duplicate. Where is it described what they are? That question inspired this question because it doesn't address what they actually are/how they work/are supposed to work, but only has how to turn them off. There is no info in Spyder about it that I've seen (e.g., when you hover over the checkbox), or Google. Updated my Q to clarify, voted to reopen.

Comment: You said: "Where is it described what they are?" Well, they are described in the title of the question.

Comment: I add my virtual vote to re-open the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Fallback completions are those completions provided by the tokens present in the file (i.e. any word on it, be it code, comments or strings), plus some Python builtin keywords (e.g. `finally`).